# Перенос проекта Visual Studio c windows на Mac (Visual studio for Mac)

Tags: c#, mac

Всем привет!

Есть пара проектов которые написаны на .Net framework4 (Webforms).
Нужно продолжить разработку на Mac - там стоит Visual Studio for Mac.

Как перенести проект туда???
Гугл толково ничего ничего не выводит...

Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Webforms - не а, не получится. На маке можно работать только с .Net Core, ASP.Net Core.

Comment: А если бы проект был на Net Core, то как перенести его????
Или его можно просто копировать и все?

Comment: Можно скопировать. Но программисты пользуются git и просто делают клонирование на машину репозитория проекта с github.